# How to Override Children.Add method of Canvas class in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, overriding

I already have a Custom Canvas class in which i have override the 'OnMoseDown' method.
But now i also want to override 'Children.Add' method.
But i didnt find any solution.

I want to get Child.ActualWidth when a child gets added to canvas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found my answer by myself. Hope this may help someone on some day.

Just added a Add method in my Custom class

```
public void Add(UserControl element)
{
    bool alreadyExist = false;
    element.Uid = element.Name;
    foreach (UIElement child in this.Children)
    {
        if (child.Uid == element.Uid)
        {
            alreadyExist = true;
            this.BringToFront(child);
        }
    }
    if (!alreadyExist)
    {
        this.Children.Add(element);
        this.UpdateLayout();
        double top = (this.ActualHeight - element.ActualHeight) / 2;
        double left = (this.ActualWidth - element.ActualWidth) / 2;
        Canvas.SetLeft(element, left);
        Canvas.SetTop(element, top);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will likely not work correctly.  A child will get added before it's `ActualWidth` is set, as that property gets set during the layout phase.

Depending on your goals here, you may want to consider overriding [`MeasureOverride`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride.aspx) and [`ArrangeOverride`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.arrangeoverride.aspx) instead, and [making a custom layout panel](http://www.wpftutorial.net/CustomLayoutPanel.html) instead of subclassing `Canvas`.

Comment: but how will i get the added child in this method as they accept size

Comment: @KishoreJangid If you make your own panel class, as the article I linked showed, you can get your `InternalChildren` at any point in time... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.internalchildren.aspx

Comment: how that i add in my previous drag canvas